# Trouble with PyGameUI - RaspberryPi

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi

I have a Pythonscript where I want to import pygameui. When I perform:

`sudo pip install pygameui`

in the terminal, I get the following message:

> Downloading/unpacking pygameui   Running setup.py egg_info for package
>   pygameui
>        Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-12.0.4-py2.7.egg
>   (from pygameui) Downloading/unpacking pygame>=1.9.1 (from pygameui)
>   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame>=1.9.1
>   (from pygameui) (from versions: ) No distributions matching the
>   version for pygame>=1.9.1 (from pygameui) Storing complete log in
>   /root/.pip/pip.log

I am struggling to solve this issue. Can somebody help me?

Comment: install pygame from source first http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

Comment: "python-pygame is already the newest version" :-(

Comment: What is your version of pygame?

Comment: pygame.version.var tells me '1.9.1release'

Comment: Do you have two python installs?

Comment: Yes Sir, Python 2.7.3 and 3.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module has not been updated for 3 years but a workaround is:

First download the master from github:

git clone https://github.com/fictorial/pygameui.git

Then `cd pygameui`

Open `setup.py` with an editor and remove `pygame>=1.9.1`  from `install_requires=['setuptools', 'pygame>=1.9.1'] -> ['setuptools']`.

Finally run `sudo python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "solution", only workarounds here.

To have working environment I install system package with pygame (i.e. `pacman -S python2-pygame` in Arch Linux) then create virtualenv with `--system-site-packages` switch. Pygame has not been updated for more than 5 years so it's highly unlikely that any changes will come in foreseable future. Later in this virtualenv I can install PygameUI with `--no-deps` switch to skip dependency checks - Pygame is already installed in required version.